# How to get the proper contrast color of a background color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to decide the color of a `Text` based on the background color of a `Container` (white text color for darker background color and black for brighter color). For that, I have used the `computeLuminance()` method of the `Color` class on the background color of the `Container`, and it works perfectly fine. But when a color is an opacity of another color, then it does not work as expected, because the luminance value of a color and its opacity colors is the same. The code is as follows:

```
Color color1 = Color(0xFF267DBD);
Color color2 = color1.withOpacity(0.2);

Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: color1,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Container1",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: color1.computeLuminance() > 0.5
                          ? Colors.black
                          : Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: color2,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Container2",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: color2.computeLuminance() > 0.5
                          ? Colors.black
                          : Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Ther result is:

[image]

The luminance values are:

```
color1 Luminance: 0.1875342335715254
color2 Luminance: 0.1875342335715254
```

I want the text of the second `Container` to have a black color to have a proper contrast with its background color.
How can we achieve this behavior, or how can we get the real luminance value of the second color, because right now the color looks brighter but the luminance value is the same as its opaque version!

**Note: Tell me if I am not clear!**

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to blend black color and color1 to get new color.

```
Color color1 = Color(0xFF267DBD);
Color color2 = Color.alphaBlend(color1.withOpacity(0.2),Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15));
```

This will return below output. You can check the luminous value .You can increase or decrease black opacity based on your requirement.

[image]